# How to select parts of different columns based on start a date column & merge into a single column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to select values from different columns(different version of same column e.g. datecol,col1_v1, col1_v2,col1_v3....) based on start and end date of the datecol (as each version start and ends on a specific date) and merge them into a single column

I have got the start and end date as a key value pair and using the .between function , I am able to get values for each column based on filter condition between date conditions.(within a loop) However I need to get all the results as one single column.

```scala
df.withColumn("resultColumn",col("col1_v1").where(col("datecol").between(startdate,enddate))
```

The above is in a loop where depending on the start date and end date it selects from a different column versions. And it has to merge the result as a single column.

```
datecol     col1_v1 col1_v2 col1_v3 result
01/01/2019  11      21      31      11
02/01/2019  12      22      32      22
03/01/2019  13      23      33      33
```

Comment: pls, provide some sample data or schema as well as the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the some concatenation functions, for example with concat_ws:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.concat_ws

dataframe.withColumn("resultColumn1",col("col_v1")).
  withColumn("resultColumn2", col("col_v2")).
  withColumn("resultColumn3", col("col_v3")).
  withColumn("result", concat_ws(",", dataframe.columns.filter(el => el != "date_col").
  map(c => col(c)): _*)).show()
```

gives:

```
+----------+------+------+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------+
|  date_col|col_v1|col_v2|col_v3|resultColumn1|resultColumn2|resultColumn3|  result|
+----------+------+------+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------+
|01/01/2019|    11|    21|    31|           11|           21|           31|11,21,31|
|02/01/2019|    12|    22|    32|           12|           22|           32|12,22,32|
|03/01/2019|    13|    23|    33|           13|           23|           33|13,23,33|
+----------+------+------+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------+
```